# Mysql match...against vs. simple like "%term%"

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

What's wrong with:

```
$term = $_POST['search'];

function buildQuery($exploded,$count,$query)
{
   if(count($exploded)>$count) 
   {
      $query.= ' AND column LIKE "%'. $exploded[$count] .'%"';
      return buildQuery($exploded,$count+1,$query);
   }
   return $query;
}

$exploded = explode(' ',$term);
$query = buildQuery($exploded,1,
'SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE "%'. $exploded[0] .'%"');
```

and then query the db to retrieve the results in a certain order, instead of using the myIsam-only sql match...against?

Would it dawdle performance dramatically?

Comment: btw I know this topic has been totally badgered and abused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is in the algorithm's that MySQL uses behind the scenes find your data. Fulltext searches also allow you sort based on relevancy. The `LIKE` search in most conditions is going to do a full table scan, so depending on the amount of data, you could see performance issues with it. The fulltext engine can also have performance issues when dealing with large row sets.

On a different note, one thing I would add to this code is something to escape the exploded values. Perhaps a call to `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: so any idea which would hinder performance more?

and yes of course you're right, a mysql_real_escape_string() would be well placed there.

Comment: In my personal experience like searches tend to be more performance intensive. This is most true when using wild cards that won't allow mysql to optimize the query to us an index on the field.

Answer (score 6):

You can check out my recent presentation I did for MySQL University:

http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Practical_Full-Text_Search_in_MySQL

Slides are also here:

http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql

In my test, using `LIKE '%pattern%'` was more than 300x slower than using a MySQL `FULLTEXT` index.  My test data was 1.5 million posts from the StackOverflow October data dump.

Comment: I'm afraid that your comparison method was a little bit wrong. LIKE is slower when you're searching in big tables but it doesn't affect the speed of data insertion to the DB. Matches has better performance when you're searching but it seriously affects the speed of insertion because each INSERT or UPDATE requires reindexation. So it is up to developer which operation has higher priority.

Comment: I did compare the performance of indexing an existing dataset, but you're right I did not test the performance of inserting more data.  I don't think MySQL's fulltext indexing needs to reindex the whole dataset when you insert -- as far as I know only Sphinx needs to do that.

Comment: As far as I know, MySQL fulltext indexes are reindexed automatically after each insert or update operation. If I'm wrong, could you tell me a reason why in some cases fulltext indexes make insertion two times slower?

Btw, a new version of Sphinx supports real time indexing but in most cases these kind of indexes are less efficient.