# MySQL Search by Relevance of all fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am sure this is possible but I think it maybe just very complex to write. I want to search every field by:

`='SearchTerm'`
then
`Like %SearchTerm`
then
`like SearchTerm%`
and finally 
`like %SearchTerm%`. I want to run this on every field in my table which there is around 30 or 40. Is there an easy way to run this over multiple fields or will I have to declare every single one?

I think I have seen a query before where different matches between %query %query% etc are ranked by assigning an integer value and then ordering by this. Would that be possible on a query like this?

Any advice and help in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Not following the question, what does'query Like %query and like query%' mean? Does query represent the field name?

Comment: @Rottingham No. It represents the search term

Comment: I have changed the wording to try and help.

Comment: why would you want to do that? if you just search by `LIKE %query%` it would return the same results?

Comment: So you want to iterate over every field of a given table and perform the given checks `='query'`, `like '%query'`, `like 'query%'`, `like '%query%'`?

Comment: confused but perhaps full-text search is what your looking for:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: I think you might want to address your db structure and what you are trying to achieve first - I know what you are trying to do (I think) find which column a particular term is located in?

Comment: If you have 30 - 40 columns you're searching it sounds like you need to normalise your data first. Quite possibly, those columns should be in a table.

Comment: fulltext is not an option as this is on a prebuilt and populated db sadly. I am simply trying to search every field for a word and any rows that match closer than other I want to rank higher

Comment: you could create a new table\db for searching that s populated from the existing system, double the space required, but has its merits.

Comment: Here is an blog post : http://blog.marceloaltmann.com/en-using-the-mysql-fulltext-index-search-pt-utilizando-mysql-fulltext/

Answer (score 1):

You should use fulltext indexing on the fields you want searched and use MATCH AGAINST instead of LIKE %%.    It's much faster and returns results based on relevancy.   More info here:

[Mysql match...against vs. simple like "%term%"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956236/mysql-match-against-vs-simple-like-term)

Comment: By the way.. if you're using innodb tables and you haven't upgraded to 5.6, you'll need to do that, or change the tables to MyISAM so that full text indexing is available.

Answer (score 0):

You should really have some sort of id to select the rows in your table.

You should have put a column with

```
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Then you could use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE "%SearchTerm%" AND id BETWEEN 1 AND 40
```

Comment: What does the Between 1 and 40 achieve?

Comment: I have updated the query and should now work. It will show your search term per the entire column as long as you have an id column

Comment: Thanks but what does the last section exactly do? Ie the Between part

Comment: Your table should have a column named id (This is so you can identify each row). You should make your id column a primary key and incremental. So the first row should have an id of 1... and your 40th row would have an id of 40 (for example). So "Between 1 and 40" is simply looking in each row for your search term.

Comment: I want to search all rows though

Answer (score 0):

I do something very similar to what you're describing (in php and mysql)

Here's my code:

```
$search = trim($_GET["search"]);
$searches = explode(" ",$search);
$sql = "SELECT *,wordmatch+descmatch+usagematch+bymatch as `match` FROM (SELECT id,word,LEFT(description,100)as description, 
         IFNULL((SELECT sum(vote)
                 FROM vote v
                 WHERE v.definition_id = d.id),0) as votecount,
            ";
$sqlword = "";
$sqldesc = "";
$sqlusage = "";
$sqlby = "";
foreach ($searches as $value) {
    $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$value);
       $sqlword = $sqlword . "+ IFNULL(ROUND((LENGTH(word) - LENGTH(REPLACE(UPPER(word), UPPER('$value'), '')))/LENGTH('$value')),0)";
       $sqldesc = $sqldesc . "+ IFNULL(ROUND((LENGTH(description) - LENGTH(REPLACE(UPPER(description), UPPER('$value'), '')))/LENGTH('$value')),0)";
     $sqlusage = $sqlusage . "+ IFNULL(ROUND((LENGTH(`usage`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(UPPER(`usage`), UPPER('$value'), '')))/LENGTH('$value')),0)";
       $sqlby = $sqlby     . "+ IFNULL(ROUND((LENGTH(`by`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(UPPER(`by`), UPPER('$value'), '')))/LENGTH('$value')),0)";
}     
$sql = $sql . $sqlword ." as wordmatch,"
            . $sqldesc ." as descmatch,"
            . $sqlusage ." as usagematch,"
            . $sqlby ." as bymatch 
        FROM definition d
        HAVING (wordmatch > 0 OR descmatch > 0 OR usagematch > 0 OR bymatch > 0)
        ORDER BY 
        wordmatch DESC,
        descmatch DESC,
        usagematch DESC,
        bymatch DESC,
        votecount DESC)T1";
$queries[] = $sql;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

You can see this at work http://unurbandictionary.comule.com/view_search.php?search=George+Miley+Cyrus this is when I search for "George Miley Cyrus"
What it does is it explodes the search string to find each word and returns the number of occurences of each word in each of my column, and then i do an ORDER BY to have relevance (priority) to come back first. So in my case `word` field has the highest relevance, then `description` field, then `usage` field, then `by` field.
Before this version of my code I was using `LIKE` but it didn't give me a count of occurences, since I want the row with the most occurences of my search word to return first before other rows.

Comment: That seems just insane. There is no way that query has any level of operational efficiency.

Comment: How else can you get count of occurences from each field? I'd like to know if there's another method.

Comment: How do you know he wants to count occurences, that is not specified in the question.

Comment: Maybe he doesn't. But do you know another method to improve my query?

Comment: I wouldn't even try.  I would use full text search.